# Bootstrap tabbed navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using this tabbed menu with twitter bootstrap.

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can go to the next tab by clicking on it, I want to find out if i can add a link/button and visit the next tab from the previous tab.

Answer (score 1):

check out my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6bf7nvc/

Be sure to check that you included your jquery.js before your bootstrap.js

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

version: jquery 2.1.0 and bootstrap 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bootstrap Tabs documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs) you can do it with Javascript:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
})
</script>
```

You need only to create a link to that function, or if using unobtrusive JavaScript, create an event handler catching the 'click' on the link. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15987733/1006863) if you need more information about it.

Answer (score -1):

SEE this `DEMO`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qSqpD/780/)**

**js**

```
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})

$('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
```

Comment: Yeah that is what i have already, I am asking if i can link to section 2 from section one with a button of some sort. Thanks